# Where Image gets stored in Android phone when i use Universal Image Loader library?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, instagram-api

I am using:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrls.get(position), holder.ivPhoto, options);
```

Where imageUrls is a ArrayList of String which is the urls list from where the images are loaded and holder contains the ImageView. 
To share this image i want to use this [Intent](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/#) But i don't know the location of the image saved. I have searched on Stack Overflow but can't fine the appropriate solution, or If there is any other way to share the image that will very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image from url

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

OR

You can add your own image loader class eg : [link](http://sourabhkarkal.com/blogspot/?p=14)
you will find DownImageLoader.java class in the constructor a cache directory is created where you will get all your files

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong library. UIL library is used for caching the image. It is not used for downloading the image and storing it in sdcard.

You can refer this link for downloading the image and retreiving the image path.

http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Downloading-and-Retrieving-Files-on-SD-card-in-Android-using-Android-SDK-in-Eclipse

Comment: No i don't think so, My images are loaded from the urls... but i don't know where